# Flex item should obtain all rest of width in line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have flex container and 3 flex-items(Item 1, Item 2, Item 3) inside.

I need to make the following things:

- Item 1 should be on top
- Item 2 should be under Item 1
- Item 3 should be on the same line with Item 2

Additional requirements:
Width of line for example is 700px;
Item 2 and Item 3 together should have overall 700px, but if container will resize to smaller size ( for example: 650px ), Item 2 and Item 3 together should have overall 650px.

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item-1" />
  <div class="item-2" />
  <div class="item-3" />
</div>
```

Currently I did almost all, but when I resize window to smaller resolution, Item 3 droped down under Item 2.

```
.flex-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item-2 {
   flex-basis: 78%;
}

.item-3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[image: Mockup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-container>* {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item-1 {
  flex-basis: 100%; /*Full width of the first line*/
}

.item-2,
.item-3 {
  flex: 1; /* Fill the space equally on the second line*/
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item-3">3</div>
</div>
```